# <li> on the same line - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I have this code:

```
 <div class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
      <li class="nav-header">Pacientes</li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><img src="../../img/catalogo_pacientes.png"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Editar Paciente</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="../../img/add_paciente.png"/></a></li>
      <li class="nav-header">Administrativo</li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="../../img/exportar_dados.png"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Adicionar Campos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.well -->
```

Can't figure out how to make it as the li content stay on the same line, preferably with some padding between them.

I'm making some tests with display:inline, but I can't figure the right way to put it on CSS

-- EDIT --

I'm having a few issues to add a comment here, so I'll just edit here.

The solution you presented worked! Thank you!

Comment: And here's the test website I'm making:
http://temporario.web929.uni5.net/interno/restrito.html#

Comment: You don't need to add comments. Instead mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To display a list on one line, the css needs to have `display: inline` property. This property must be applied on the `li` element.

This CSS will work fine. Notice the padding too.

```
ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

While coding, please give your `<ul>` element an ID and then apply the CSS on that ID instead of applying it on generic `<li>` element.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g9qkr4vw/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 you can use the Flexbox utilities for a cleaner alternative to inline styling.  I faced a similar problem getting glyphicons and text in a `<li>` to stay on the same line.  Here's how I solved the problem.

```
<ul class="nav navbar navbar-left d-flex d-inline-flex ">
  <li class="nav-item d-inline-flex  align-items-center mr-2"><a class="nav-link d-inline-flex" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-o mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item d-inline-flex  align-items-center mr-2"><a class="nav-link d-inline-flex" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here I'm using glyphicons from Font Awesome.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjkind/qc3bscxy/23/) that uses the `.list-inline` and `.list-inline-item` classes on the unordered list.

Here is another [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjkind/2sq9xf3c/4/) that also works and uses inline flexboxes in Bootstrap 4.

Either method should work.